# Telerik namespace cannot be resolved in ASP.NET MVC Razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, telerik, telerik-reporting

I'm trying to render Telerik Reporting (Q2 2014 SP1 - trial version) in my ASP.NET MVC 4 application (which uses .NET 4.5 framework), but for some reason "Telerik." namespace cannot be resolved in ASP.NET MVC Razor view, although I can access "Telerik." namespace in controller.

Razor view:

```
@using Telerik - error is in here
@Html.TelerikReporting() - error is in here
```

Web.config:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="Telerik.Reporting" />
        <add namespace="Telerik.ReportViewer.Mvc" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Telerik libraries my ASP.NET MVC project is referencing:

```
Telerik.Reporting
Telerik.ReportViewer.Mvc
```

What can be the issue with my set up?

Comment: Which web.config did you add this to? You need to add it to the web.config under the Views folder.

Comment: This is Views/web.config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem.

I've been desperately trying following approaches: running solution in VS2012, deleted *bin*, *obj* folders, moving libraries from one path to another, restarting machine and VS numerous times and everything was futile.

However I've noticed that *Telerik.Reporting.dll* and *Telerik.ReportViewer.Mvc.dll* were not getting copied in my *bin* folder. In Visual Studio I expanded "References", clicked on each dll file and went to each dll's "Properties" and toggled "Copy Local" property from "False" to "True".

I cleaned and rebuilt my MVC project, checked that the Telerik dll files appeared in *bin* folder, went to my Razor view and `@Html.TelerikReporting()` worked!

Out of curiosity I toggled "Copy Local" property from "True" to "False", repeated the rest of the process and `@Html.TelerikReporting()` still worked. I don't know if there is a problem with Visual Studio or my "Professional" installation.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need a

```
@using Telerik
```

if the appropriate namespaces are imported in your web.config. Sometimes in order for your Razer views to pick up on the web.config namespaces after being initially added, you need to restart visual studio for some reason.

I would validate that "Telerik" is the appropriate namespace for the TelerikReporting method you're trying to access.

Additionally, you have a syntax error in:

```
@Html.TelerikReporting()
```

It should (likely) be

```
@(Html.TelerikReporting())
```

Comment: Tried with brackets, still doesn't work. Also I've tried to clean/rebuild the solution - nothing. Restarted Visual Studio - nothing. Restarted PC - nothing.

Comment: "@using Telerik" is just to show that this namespace doesn't appear neither in IntelliSence, nor in runtime compilation.